# How to troubleshoot problems under ASP.NET out of process Session State

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

We are migrating a monolithic ASP.NET MVC web application from single server to farm under load balancer.  It relies heavily on Session data, so we are moving from In Process to Out, either the ASP.NET State Service or SQL Server.  The behaviour I describe happens with both.

The first problem we encountered was serialization.  A bunch of data is stuffed into the Session with a bunch of techniques (old program, many hands over the years).  Sometimes objects with a deep graph.  The answer appeared to be to attribute each class in the graph with [Serializable].  Before doing so, requests would return 500 and garbage data.  After attributing all of the offending classes, 200 came back and real data.  Hooray!

Except: after partially loading the home page, everything clears and the home page begins loading again.  Then clears again and reloads.  Infinite loop.

By merely changing back to In Process, the application behaves perfectly.  Changing either to State Server or SQL Server causes the same loop to occur.

My question is not how to fix our web application - I have not provided enough details for that.  My question is how do we diagnose this?  Does the behaviour I describe provide a clue where we should look?  Is there a way to debug/trace while under out of proc session management?  Are there tools that can provide insight?

So far we have resorted to "let's try *this* and see if it works"  Versions of "this" include adding [Serializable] to everything, dumping "I am here" to a log, rubbing lucky totems.  No clues (let alone solutions) so far.

To be clear: we are not under LB yet.  This is a single server and the only change we are making is switching between ( ) In process, ( ) State Server, and ( ) SQL Server  So I don't think I'm worrying about Machine Key or AppDomainID yet.  I'm fairly confident both State Service and SQL server are set up correctly.  We've gotten past connection errors etc., and when using SQL Server there are rows in the ASPStateTempSessions table (and one in the ASPStateTempApplications table)

How can I track down this strange looping behaviour and make the app behave under Out Of Process state management the way it does when it is In Process?